# How to add new email template and call/ use that template in prestashop 1.6

Tags: email, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a module in which I am displaying all the dormant users by combining two tables - customer and order table and now I Want to perform bulk action (mail send action ) to the dormant users , But I want to make a email template in which this template can be  edited  and used  for sending email to the dormant users from the BO.
How to send  email using a template  in prestashop ? .
I created a email template (created.html and .text file ) in email folder, Also edited  classes/Langugae.php

```
      // Added natives mails files
       $mFiles = array(
        'account.html', 'account.txt',
        'backoffice_order.html', 'backoffice_order.txt',
        'bankwire.html', 'bankwire.txt',
        'cheque.html', 'cheque.txt',
        'contact.html', 'contact.txt',
        'contact_form.html', 'contact_form.txt',
        'credit_slip.html', 'credit_slip.txt',
        'download_product.html', 'download_product.txt',
        'employee_password.html', 'employee_password.txt',
        'forward_msg.html', 'forward_msg.txt',
        'guest_to_customer.html', 'guest_to_customer.txt',
        'in_transit.html', 'in_transit.txt',
        'log_alert.html', 'log_alert.txt',
        'newsletter.html', 'newsletter.txt',
        'order_canceled.html', 'order_canceled.txt',
        'order_conf.html', 'order_conf.txt',
        'order_customer_comment.html', 'order_customer_comment.txt',
        'order_merchant_comment.html', 'order_merchant_comment.txt',
        'order_return_state.html', 'order_return_state.txt',
        'outofstock.html', 'outofstock.txt',
        'password.html', 'password.txt',
        'password_query.html', 'password_query.txt',
        'payment.html', 'payment.txt',
        'payment_error.html', 'payment_error.txt',
        'preparation.html', 'preparation.txt',
        'refund.html', 'refund.txt',
        'reply_msg.html', 'reply_msg.txt',
        'shipped.html', 'shipped.txt',
        'test.html', 'test.txt',
        'voucher.html', 'voucher.txt',
        'voucher_new.html', 'voucher_new.txt',
        'order_changed.html', 'order_changed.txt',
        'dormant_email.html', 'dormant_email.txt'
    );
```

I added  my email template -    'dormant_email.html', 'dormant_email.txt' in  mails\en folder

Answer (score 2):

ok  I solved this by adding the template file  by creating mail.en folder in module folder  ( modulename/emails/en/)

and  by below code

```
                    if (!Mail::Send(
                    $this->context->language->id,
                    'dormant_email',
                    Mail::l('Hello Long  Time  No See ! Please Visit and Get a Chance to Win'),
                    $templateVars, 
                    $dormantUserEmailID,
                    null, null, null, null, null, dirname(__FILE__).'/mails/', true, $this->context->shop->id))
        die('0') ;echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Email Send');</script>"; return true;
    die('1');echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Email not Send');</script>"; return false;
```

I am able to send email and use the template and it is been listing when I click on the 
 Localization->transalations -->modify transalations 
select email template translations and  select English and click modify button  and in the modules when u expand your module the email template can be seen and can be edited  by edit tool  .

Comment: Hi, I have create like your structures.
But still not call the new template in {modulename/mails/en/template_mail.html}. Any solution?